# How to make expandable recycler view in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, android-recyclerview, xamarin.android

I've googled a lot but couldn't find anything. All the tutorials are only for Android Studio.

**I am trying to make something like-**

[image]

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Do you mind if directly use `ExpandableListView`?

Comment: Does the same approach work for recycler view too?